# display all markers on map

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api-2, marker

I want to display all the markers on Google map in my application, with info window and when click on the info window it should take me to another activity for description.
I am able to show all the marker on the map, but when i click on the info window it takes me to the last item stored in my database.. What i am doing wrong ?
 Here is my code:

```
Cursor c1 = newDB.rawQuery("SELECT name,latitude,longtude,category_type FROM facilities " , null);

        if (c1 != null ) {
            if  (c1.moveToFirst()) {
                do {

                 double   latitude =c1.getDouble(c1.getColumnIndex("latitude"));
                 double   longitude = c1.getDouble(c1.getColumnIndex("longtude"));
                 String cat =c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("category_type"));
                  nnn = c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("name"));
                 GeoPoint  p = new GeoPoint(
                            (int)(latitude *1E6 ), 
                            (int)(longitude *1E6 ));
                    //Write a code to display this point on google-map
               //  map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title(nnn));

                 if ("Monuments".equals(cat))
                {
                Marker melbourne = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
                .title(nnn)
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.palace)));

                onInfoWindowClick(melbourne);
                map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
                     Intent intent = new Intent(NearbyActivity.this,Description.class);
                     intent.putExtra("id", nnn);
                     startActivity(intent);
                              } });
                }
```

It takes the value of the title(the variable nnn) on the info window right, only when i click on the info window it makes the variable (nnn) the last item stored in database. I need help for that Please.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Different markers show same infowindow content android google map v2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19763763/different-markers-show-same-infowindow-content-android-google-map-v2)

Comment: i think it is different, because my code is in loop in cursor and the data are from an external database, also i don't have an adapter for info window, i used onInfoWindowClick()

Comment: The structure of your and the other question's code might differ, but both contain the same error (setting `OnInfoWindowClickListener`/`InfoWindowAdapter` multiple times) and thus the same incorrect behaviour as a result. Read first and last paragraph of my answer there. These apply to your question.